# How to extract more points from graph in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a graph with 6 cycles for one cycle i given data given bilow and for next cycles same data repeating pasted the graph the star points are actual data points and the black which i manually kept that data has to be extract how to do it in python
This is my data:

```
Efficiency
0
0
59.02
60
56.54
56.54
62.63
61.94
61.94
62.9
59.02
0
```

And I plotted the graph with this data:

[image: how can we get the data which pointed in blue color]

This is the code i used for plotting:

```
x=df["Efficiency"]
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig= plt.figure(figsize=(25,6))
axes= fig.add_axes([0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8])
axes.plot(x,color='green',lw=3,marker="*",ms=15,mec = 'r')
plt.xlim(0,72)
plt.ylim(0,65)
plt.show()
```

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqdFT.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y26dw.png)

Comment: Hi. Please clarify what you want. What do you mean by 'what i want is for every two points need the values'.
Also, from where are the blue points? Do you need the coordinates of these points? If so, what is known about them?

Comment: I pasted image and related data above between two points means 0 to 0 and  0 to  59.02 points there will be a sub points need that subpoints values

Comment: Those blue data points manually  I kept  need the data which I kept blue points

Comment: It looks like you might be trying to **interpolate** --- you want to get values for data points _in between_ the data points you have. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes exactly correct

Answer (score 1):

Since your plot is piece-wise linear, I suggest to caculate the corresponding linear curve for each piece:

```
def interpolate_line(p1, p2, x):
    # p1 and p2 are two of your given points
    # x is a list of positions at which you are interested in the value
    # linear curve y = a*x + b
    
    a = (p2[1]-p1[1])/(p2[0]-p1[0])
    b = (p1[1]*p2[0]-p2[1]*p1[0])/(p2[0]-p1[0])

    # insert all your x values into the linear curve to get their corresponding values
    y = [a*ix + b for ix in x]
    return y
```

and then feed the points of interest to it:

```
# generating given points
points = [(ix, iy) for ix, iy in enumerate(x)] # x is your x from the df above
for p1, p2 in zip(points[:-1], points[1:]): 
    corresponding_values = interpolate_line(p1, p2, your_list_of_positions_for_that_piece_of_curve)
```

Comment: getting error for above code

Comment: edited the entire data previously for one cycle i given data the curve is not piece wise

Comment: I'm sorry, an '*' was missing. I edited the code, it is running now. 
What do you mean by 'the curve is not piece wise'? From your image still between each given pair of points the curve is linear so the provided code still applies.

Answer (score 0):

for my data `y = df["Efficiency"]` which are **12** values generated `x` values by using linspace `x = np.linspace(0, 12, 24)` generated **24** values and converted *array* to dataframe and used interpolation method  `u = np.interp([x], df.x, df.Efficiency)` and got the corresponding y values that is stored in `"u"` finally I tried with my entire data got the graph like this:

[image: this]